# Unable to use Tomcat : "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" on Chrome

Tags: tomcat, camunda

I need to use Camunda and I am trying to do so with Tomcat.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/dmn11/install/).

When I run start-camunda.bat, it opens a console window. The following text is displayed:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\CamundaTomcat\server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\CamundaTomcat\server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\CamundaTomcat\server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\CamundaTomcat\server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\CamundaTomcat\server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
C:\Program Files\CamundaTomcat\server\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin>
```

A new tab opens in Chrome. The address is http://localhost:8080/camunda-welcome/index.html. It says localhost denied the connection. I tried removing the "camunda-welcome/index.html" part but it still denies the connection.

I tried Edge and it gives me a similar error (INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND).

I tried changing the server.xml file to have Tomcat use port 8083, then 8181. All it does it generate the same error.

What else can I try?

Thank you!

UPDATE: I ended up downloading WildFly to use it instead of Tomcat, and it works.

Comment: Is your firewall blocking that port? Perhaps try turning it off and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately, I still have the same problem.